# Ionic 2- Alert Dialog with button handlers on different components

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, alert

I have ionic2 application and I want to use common alert controller.
So I can transfer all data through method parameters. On each component screen Alert dialogs button should be handled separately. How can I write such alert so I can handle button click on separate component as per need.
Please help I am new to Ionic2
.Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is shared provider for Alert

**Shared.provider.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Injectable()
export class SharedProvider { 
  constructor(private _alert: AlertController) { }
  public Alert = {
    confirm: (msg?, title?) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let alert = this._alert.create({
          title: title || 'Confirm',
          message: msg || 'Do you want continue?',
          buttons: [
            {
              text: 'Cancel',
              role: 'cancel',
              handler: () => {
                reject(false);
              }
            },
            {
              text: 'Ok',
              handler: () => {
                resolve(true);
              }
            }
          ]
        });
        alert.present();
      });

    },
    alert: (msg, title?) => {
      let alert = this._alert.create({
        title: title || 'Alert',
        subTitle: msg,
        buttons: ['Dismiss']
      });

      alert.present();
    }
  }
}
```

Usage

**Home.ts**

```
import { SharedProvider } from '../../providers/shared.provider';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    providers: [SharedProvider]
})
export class HomePage {
    constructor(public shared: SharedProvider) {}

    deletePost(gossip) {
        this.shared.Alert.confirm().then((res) => {
            console.log('confirmed');
        }, err => {
            console.log('user cancelled');
        })
    }
}
```

You can add more common functionality. Like for toast msg add-

```
 public Toast = {
    show: (text: string, duration?, position?, closeButton?, btnText?) => {
      this._toastMsg = this._toastCtrl.create({
        message: text,
        duration: duration || closeButton ? null : 3000,
        position: position || 'top',
        showCloseButton: closeButton || false,
        closeButtonText: btnText || 'OK'
      });
      this._toastMsg.present();
    },
    hide() {
      this._toastMsg.dismiss();
    }
  }
```

Now display toast like `this.shared.Toast.show('message');`. Similarly you can add Storage, Loader and other common function here.

Comment: Thank you for your response...please give me some time i will check.

Comment: Thanks for your your answer, it helped me a lot. Just one remark: reject(false); did not work for me (it generated an error), but resolve(false); works fine.