# Authenticating my Ionic 3 app against Spring Boot REST API

Tags: spring, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

The question must be very typical, but I can't really find a good comparison.

I'm new to Ionic & mobile dev.
We have a REST API (Spring Boot).
API is currently used by AngularJS 1.5 front-end only.
AngularJS app is authenticated based on the standard session-based authentication.

What should I use to authenticate an ionic 3 app?
As I understand, have 2 options:

1. Use the same auth as for Angular front-end.
2. implement oauth2 on the back-end and use the token for the ionic app.

As for now, I understand that implementing oauth2 at back-end is a way to go because with the option #1 I should store the username & password in the local storage (ionic app), which is not safe. Otherwise, if I don't do that - the user will have to authenticate each time the app was launched. Am I right?

So, that leaves me with option #2 - store oauth2 token on the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final solution i've made:

**ionic app:**

implemented a jwt token storage similar to `Swapnil Patwa` answer.

**Spring back-end:**

Tried to use their original ouath2 package, but found out that as always with spring/java, configs are too time-consuming => made a simple filter which is checking for the manually generated & assigned jwt token.

Comment: Great. Accept answer to complete the question.

Answer (score 1):

Good to go with #2. Here is how i manage token.
I use ionic storage to store token and a provider config.ts which hold the token during run time.

**config.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';  
@Injectable()
export class TokenProvider { 
    public token: any;
    public user: any = {}; 

  constructor(  ) { }
  setAuthData (data) { 
    this.token = data.token; 
    this.user = data
  }
  dropAuthData () {
    this.token = null;
    this.user = null;
  }
}
```

**auth.ts**

```
import { TokenProvider} from '../../providers/config';

constructor(public tokenProvider: TokenProvider) { }

login() {
      this.api.authUser(this.login).subscribe(data => {
        this.shared.Loader.hide(); 
          this.shared.LS.set('user', data); 
          this.tokenProvider.setAuthData(data); 
          this.navCtrl.setRoot(TabsPage); 
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
        this.submitted = false;
        this.shared.Loader.hide();
        this.shared.Toast.show('Invalid Username or Password');
        this.login.password = null;
      });
}
```

and i do a check when app launch. 
**app.component.ts** (in constructor)

```
shared.LS.get('user').then((data: any) => {
      if (!data) {
        this.rootPage = AuthPage;
      } else {
        tokenProvider.setAuthData(data);
        this.rootPage = TabsPage;
      } 
    });
```

**api.provider.ts**

```
  updateUser(data): Observable < any > {
        let headers = new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-AUTH-TOKEN': (this.tokenProvider.token)
        });
    return this.http.post(`${baseUrl}/updateUser`, JSON.stringify(data), {
            headers: headers
        })
        .map((response: Response) => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

And last **logout.ts**

```
  logOut(): void {
    this.shared.Alert.confirm('Do you want to logout?').then((data) => {
      this.shared.LS.remove('user').then(() => {
        this.tokenProvider.dropAuthData();
        this.app.getRootNav().setRoot(AuthPage);
      }, () => {
        this.shared.Toast.show('Oops! something went wrong.');
      });
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
    })

  }
```

Comment: Thanks. what is `this.shared` ?

Comment: Also, do you mean you use this https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/ for storage?

Comment: Provider for common functionality, like loader, alert, toast and other. Check my answer to this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45143978/ionic-2-alert-dialog-with-button-handlers-on-different-components/45144618

Comment: `this.shared.LS` where LS is Local Storage. Ask me if you need LS reusable  method. Otherwise you can also go with the doc.

Comment: i probably get it, thank. will just try.
the key issue for me actually is the decision on setting up oauth2 on back-end or using session based auth and storing user:pass on user's device.

Comment: Go with the oauth2. All the best.